# Django: Custom Template Tag not found in WSGI Application

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, templatetags

I've been using custom templatetags for the first time with Django. After some trouble I got it to work with `runserver`. But now when I try to access the page through Apache (with mod_wsgi) I get the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
'webpage_helpers' is not a valid tag library: Template library webpage_helpers not found,
tried django.templatetags.webpage_helpers,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.webpage_helpers,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.webpage_helpers,webpage.templatetags.webpage_helpers
```

My file structure is the following:

```
project/
    project/
        wsgi.py
        settings.py 
    webpage/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        models.py
        templatetags/
            __init__.py
            webpage_helpers.py
    static/
    templates/
        base/
            base.html
        webpage/
            index.html
```

The error starts at `webpage/index.html`

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load webpage_helpers %}
```

My `wsgi.py` is still default, it only contains a line towards the `settings.py`.

The error shows it's clearly looking at the right spot (`webpage.templatetags.webpage_helpers`) as last item.

I've tried restarting apache through:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Keep in mind it's working perfectly with `runserver`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

This was an permission issue, my ftp isn't set up correctly and creates the files and folders with incorrect permissions. I chmodded the project to 755 for directories and 644 for files and it works now.